# PHP: where is the mime_content_type function?

Tags: php, mime-types

[The documentation for `mime_content_type`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) says

> This function has been deprecated as the PECL extension [Fileinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) provides the same functionality (and more) in a much cleaner way.

That link is to the [Fileinfo extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php). That page itself links to [its `mime_content_type` implementation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php). However, this page is *one and the same page that says that it is deprecated in favour of the Fileinfo implementation.* So there is an infinite recursive loop in the documentation.

So, what is it that has been deprecated, and where is the implementation which it has been deprecated in favour of?

Comment: If I follow [that link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) I don't see any deprecation notice anymore. Could they have undeprecated it?

Comment: Apparently it was never deprecated and just [a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71367) in the docs!

Comment: @MatthijsWessels appears they have corrected the page, yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mime_content_type` is **not deprecated**. It was apparently just a mistake in the documentation.

See [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71367)

Answer (score -1):

The new function to determine file types is `finfo_file`, which will return the file's mime type as a string (like `mime_content_type`).

`mime_content_type` has been deprecated because the `finfo_*` functions are also accessible via a more modern, object oriented class.

Comment: Apparently it was never deprecated and just [a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71367) in the docs!